# http observable<any> - Angular 4

Tags: html, arrays, xml, angular, web-services

I need to display the data on html that I get from web service. I am able to see the data in a format that I want, but I can't display properly on html. I think **-any-** in http.get is the problem. I can read data in console without **-any-** but it works fine with . When it works with it, it still does not print in html properly. Can anyone provide advice on this?

**html**

```
<div>{{this.res}}</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { IMovie } from './movie';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  res: any[] ;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private _appService: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { this.getData(); }

  getData(): void {
    this._appService.getData()
      .subscribe(
      (res: any []) => this.res = res,
      (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

  }
}
```

**app.service.ts :**

```
Injectable()
export class AppService {
private urlNorth = '';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData(): Observable<any> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/sml');
    headers.set('Accept', 'text/xml');
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    return this.http.get<any>(this.urlNorth,{responseType:'text', headers: headers})
        .do(data => {
            // console.log(data)
            var dataParsed = data.replace('<string xmlns="service">', '').replace('</string>', '').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
            // console.log(dataParsed);
            parseString(dataParsed, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    return console.dir('invalid XML');
                }
                else {
                    console.log(res);
                    console.log(res.NewDataSet.Table[0].DataPointName[0]);
                }
            })

        })

        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**data in console w/o any **

[image: 1]

{{this.res}} in html 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `<div>{{this?.res}}</div>`?

Comment: Can you show an example of what the "res" data is?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: I added sample data.

Comment: when I include <any>, i get this error : 'Argument of type '{ responseType: "text"; headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams; reportProgress?: boolean; respons...'.
  Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.
    Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'.'

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you don't have to put **any** at this line in app.service.ts

```
return this.http.get<any>(this.urlNorth,{responseType:'text', headers: headers})
```

because get method expects 0 type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Type `any` is not the problem. It's just `TypeScript` annotation to organise your code. The problem is you are refering to the `res` in inline template as `this.res`, but you should just `res`. However it won't work as you think. Looking at your data structure You will have to iterate throught this data due to `Table` is an array. Additionaly I Highly suggest to always represnt your data as `class`

```
export class Apps {
   public Table: Array<any>; //here should be another type instead of "any"
   /* rest of data if any */
}
```

Back to your question you should have in your html file `<div>{{res}}</div>` but that's just print your object as string if I good remember. So to properly access your data you should iterate through table using `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let el of res.NewDataSet.Table">
    <span>{{el.BackColor}}</span>
    <!-- all other data -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Szarik, thanks for your time. But should I not worry about <any> in http.get?

Comment: In my workplace we are making special classes for `requests` and `responses` to provide clean and well organised code. But you don't have to, I think making classes for responses it's a bit too pedantic, but surely its Helpful when you back to the code after long time.

Comment: Ah now I see there is problem with your service too

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the data is coming back. I'll answer your initial question first (since you added a few issues in comments):

My guess is when you get data back, it's not showing because it's HTML, and angular doesn't like injecting html.

Add this to your TS:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

res[]: safeHTML;
```

And change your html to this:

```
<div [innerHTML]="res"></div>
```

As mentioned in a previous answer, this is a solution for a single return of res, not an array of different htmls.  If it's an array, you'll have to handle it accordingly.  for instance:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let r of res">
   <div [innerHTML]="r">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yes, data is coming back. From it looks different than I expected. It shouldn't have <string> tag at all because I parsed it out in service.ts